# how to open sets of programs simultaneously with command line

Tags: command-line

I recently learned here how to open a program from the command line.

my question is, how can i make a set of programs open simultaneously with one command entered?

Comment: Let's have a specific example, please. What programs do you want to start?

Comment: Kontact and rekonq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a program simply by typing its name (and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course).

To run a program "in the background", giving you control of your terminal again, you can append `&`.

So:

```
gvim /etc/hosts    # Runs gvim and waits until it's finished
```

But:

```
gvim /etc/hosts &  # Runs gvim and returns control to the terminal
```

Therefore, this can be used to start three programs, one after the other:

```
kontact &
rekonq &
something_else &
```

If you can type fast enough they'll appear to start simultaneously. Or you can put all three commands on the same line, like this, so that the commands are executed only once you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
kontact & rekonq & something_else &
```

Comment: this all worked well for me except appending "&" which did not reserve active window status in the konsole program, what might be my issue? @ roaima

Comment: @WolfgangSteele I don't understand what you mean by "reserve active window status"?

Comment: appending & doesnt leave me in control of the previous terminal, but rather moves focus and control to the created window

Comment: @WolfgangSteele That's a function of your window manager.

Comment: so im assuming i need to edit that from the window manager settings? or should i get a better one? not sure which one mine is, what is the name of yours where it works?

Comment: @WolfgangSteele I didn't say it worked for me. I answered your question about starting multiple programs from the command line. Please can I suggest that you ask a new question and see if other people can help you with this separate issue.